# embedding content on facebook page

Tags: facebook, youtube, media

When I share YouTube video link on Facebook, facebook renders video in page.

Is that because YouTube supports something like oembed or facebook is doing something very custom for YouTube or combination of both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook will allow you to embed video as long as it is in SWF format, like youtube embeds. Use these [open graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags on your page:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.swf" />
<!-- these 3 are optional -->
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Comment: Correct - SWF only at the moment, which the article mentions.  But other than that they aren't doing anything custom for youtube.